# Image not uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

While signing up on the app, the user is recorded into Firebase Authentication, but it's profile picture is not uploaded to Firebase Storage. The code compiles fine too.

```
private func persistImageToStorage() {
    
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    else { return }
    
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: uid)
    
    guard let imageData = self.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
    
    ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
        if let err = err {
            self.loginStatusMessage = "Couldn't upload your photo \(err)"
            return
        }
        
        ref.downloadURL { url, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.loginStatusMessage = "Error uploading your photo \(err)"
                return
            }
            
            self.loginStatusMessage = "Photo successfully uploaded!"
            print(url?.absoluteString)
        }
    }
}
```

Searched on related questions and none are getting this same error. Firebase is also updated to the latest version!

Comment: "getting this same error" -- what is the error? Have you used the debugger to see if your code makes it through all of the stages? For example, does it make it through the `guard` statements? Does it make it into the `downloadURL` closure? Does it hit the "Couldn't upload your photo" line?

Comment: No actually! I just used breakpoints and it seems that it doesn't make it pass `ref.putData`. It also never puts the message "Couldn't upload your photo"

Comment: Does it make it into the `ref.downloadURL` closure?

Comment: Also no, and there's also no message of "Error uploading your photo"

Comment: where are you printing the message ? in loginStatusMessage didSet?

Comment: Where does self.image come from?

Comment: you could try adding a specific metadata instead of nil, such as: 

 `let metadata = StorageMetadata()`
 
 `metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"`
                        
and use: ` ref.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { metadata, err in .... }`

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed It's a State variable with an empty string that would be called to report any error, on the view

Comment: @LaBanana just a State variable of type UIImage?

Comment: @workingdog Tried that, still nothing. If it helps, I used breakpoints on both guards and edited the breakpoints with an action of debugger command, and typed po Auth.auth().currentUser and po self.image on the other one. They both run through, but the self.image throws me a nil on the console

Comment: Fixed it! it was a mistake I made with the State var image, because I had declared another  State var, called avatarImage inside the view and didn't noticed. Photo now uploads to Firebase Storage successfully. Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I forgot I had a `@State var avatarImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")!` inside a struct of type View, it was taking the picture the user selected and doing nothing, because the code was taking another `@State var` as the picture with the info, to upload to Firebase (debugger showed `self.image` was throwing nil).

Comment: If you answered your own question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @LirazShakaAmir, unfortunately, the site is not letting me flag it as you wish until 48 hours later. No idea why!